# Using AES encryption with binary FileStream, read + write

Tags: c#, .net, encryption, cryptoapi

I've hacked up some other code I've found thanks to SO.  I'm not getting any errors when writing my encrypted data to disk, but I get an "index of bounds" error inside the RijndaelManaged class when reading data back.

This is my class I'm using to create a read and write stream wrapped with AES encryption (this is my actual salt, but I'll be sure to change it before release):

```
public class Crypto
{
    private static byte[] _salt = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("42kb$2fs$@#GE$^%gdhf;!M807c5o666");

    public static Stream CreateCryptoStreamAESWrite(string sharedSecret, Stream stream)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(sharedSecret))
            throw new ArgumentNullException("sharedSecret");

        // generate the key from the shared secret and the salt
        Rfc2898DeriveBytes key = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(sharedSecret, _salt);

        // Create a RijndaelManaged object
        RijndaelManaged aesAlg = new RijndaelManaged();
        aesAlg.Key = key.GetBytes(aesAlg.KeySize / 8);

        // Create a decryptor to perform the stream transform.
        ICryptoTransform encryptor = aesAlg.CreateEncryptor(aesAlg.Key, aesAlg.IV);

        // prepend the IV
        stream.Write(BitConverter.GetBytes(aesAlg.IV.Length), 0, sizeof(int));
        stream.Write(aesAlg.IV, 0, aesAlg.IV.Length);

        CryptoStream csEncrypt = new CryptoStream(stream, encryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write);
        return csEncrypt;
    }

    public static Stream CreateCryptoStreamAESRead(string sharedSecret, Stream stream)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(sharedSecret))
            throw new ArgumentNullException("sharedSecret");

        // generate the key from the shared secret and the salt
        Rfc2898DeriveBytes key = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(sharedSecret, _salt);

        // Create a RijndaelManaged object
        // with the specified key and IV.
        RijndaelManaged aesAlg = new RijndaelManaged();
        aesAlg.Key = key.GetBytes(aesAlg.KeySize / 8);

        // Get the initialization vector from the encrypted stream
        aesAlg.IV = ReadByteArray(stream);

        // Create a decrytor to perform the stream transform.
        ICryptoTransform decryptor = aesAlg.CreateDecryptor(aesAlg.Key, aesAlg.IV);
        CryptoStream csDecrypt = new CryptoStream(stream, decryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Read);
        return csDecrypt;
    }

    private static byte[] ReadByteArray(Stream s)
    {
        byte[] rawLength = new byte[sizeof(int)];
        if (s.Read(rawLength, 0, rawLength.Length) != rawLength.Length)
            throw new SystemException("Stream did not contain properly formatted byte array");

        byte[] buffer = new byte[BitConverter.ToInt32(rawLength, 0)];
        if (s.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length) != buffer.Length)
            throw new SystemException("Did not read byte array properly");

        return buffer;
    }
}
```

Here is some test usage code I wrote:

```
        FileStream fs = new FileStream("c:\\temp\\test.dat", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.None);
        Stream cs = Crypto.CreateCryptoStreamAESWrite("test", fs);
        BinaryWriter bw = new BinaryWriter(cs);
        bw.Write("test");
        cs.Flush();
        fs.Close();
        fs = new FileStream("c:\\temp\\test.dat", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite);
        cs = Crypto.CreateCryptoStreamAESRead("test", fs);
        BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(cs);
        string test = br.ReadString();
        if (test != "test")
            throw new Exception("Your Kungfu is not good!");
        fs.Close();
```

This is the error I get on the br.ReadString() line:

```
System.IndexOutOfRangeException: Index was outside the bounds of the array.
   at System.Security.Cryptography.RijndaelManagedTransform.DecryptData(Byte[] inputBuffer, Int32 inputOffset, Int32 inputCount, Byte[]& outputBuffer, Int32 out
putOffset, PaddingMode paddingMode, Boolean fLast)
   at System.Security.Cryptography.RijndaelManagedTransform.TransformFinalBlock(
Byte[] inputBuffer, Int32 inputOffset, Int32 inputCount)
   at System.Security.Cryptography.CryptoStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
   at System.IO.Stream.ReadByte()
   at System.IO.BinaryReader.ReadByte()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like I needed to call `Close` on my Crypto stream.  I was calling `Flush`, but not Close.  I replaced cs.Flush() with cs.Close() and now it is working.

Hopefully someone can at least learn from the example code in my question, although I imagine there is an easier way to just read/write AES encrypted streams (to/from file or otherwise).

Comment: You don't have to close the CryptoStream. CryptoStream has a FlushFinalBlock method that is needed when encrypting. That is method to call when you have finished sending all the plaintext through the CryptoStream. When you call Close the CryptoStream automatically calls FlushFinalBlock. If you can arrange your work to occur inside a using() block this happens automatically.